# Return DayOfTheWeek (as an uppercase string) from a given String input

Tags: java, api, datetime, java-8, localdate

This is my first time looking into the Date Api's i don't understand where i'm going wrong. The Question has been commented out so you can see exactly whats expected.

Could someone please simply explain how to solve/approach this problem?

When i get to the DateUtil class>DayofTheWeek method i attempt to return the LocalDate.DayofTheWeek method using the *theDate* field which by now has been initialised. but it wont work. It keeps saying 'cannot resolve method'?

```
public class ChallengeThree {
    public static String dayOfWeek(String date) {
        /**
         *** Returns a String storing the day of the week in all capital letters of the
         * given date String
         * Complete the implementation of the DateUtil class and use it in this function
         * Arguments
         * date - a String storing a local date, such as "2000-01-01"
         * Examples
         * dayOfWeek("2000-01-01") returns "SATURDAY"
         */**

        // ====================================
        // Do not change the code before this

        // CODE1: Write code to return the day of the week of the String date
        //        using the DateUtil class at the bottom of this file

        DateUtil newdates= new DateUtil("2000-01-01");
        System.out.println(newdates.dayOfWeek());
        // ====================================
        // Do not change the code after this
    }

//    public static void main(String[] args) {
//        String theDayOfWeek = dayOfWeek("2000-01-01");
        String expected = "SATURDAY";
        // Expected output is
        // true
//        System.out.println(theDayOfWeek == expected);
//    }
}

class DateUtil {
    LocalDate theDate;

    public DateUtil(String date) {
        /**
         * Initialize the theDate field using the String date argument
         * Arguments
         * date - a String storing a local date, such as "2000-01-01"
         */

        // ====================================
        // Do not change the code before this


        LocalDate theNewDate = LocalDate.parse(date);
        this.theDate=theNewDate;
        // ====================================
        // Do not change the code after this
    }

    public String dayOfWeek() {
        /**
         * Return a String the day of the week represented by theDate
         */

        // ====================================
        // Do not chDate theDate = new ange the code before this

         return LocalDate.of(theDate).getDayOfWeek();
        // ====================================
        // Do not change the code after this
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you check what `LocalDate.getDayOfWeek()` returns?

Comment: So, I had a look the [JavaDocs for `LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) and there is no such method `LocalDate.of(LocalDate)` ... and I wouldn't know why there would be as it doesn't make sense.  Why not just use `theDate.getDayOfWeek()`?

Comment: You could also just use a [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) to format the "day of week" value to a `String` and uppercase it as required

Comment: Possibly off the point, but `theDayOfWeek == expected` is incorrect. [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

You are making this much too complicated.

One problem is that you are thinking in text, using dumb strings rather than smart objects. Do not be passing around the string `"2000-01-01"`, pass around a `LocalDate` object. Do not pass around the string `SATURDAY`, pass around the `DayOfWeek.SATURDAY` object.

```
LocalDate
.parse(
    "2000-01-01"
)
.getDayOfWeek()
.equals(
    DayOfWeek.SATURDAY 
)
```

If you insist on using strings against my advice, you can get the name of the [`DayOfWeek`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/DayOfWeek.html) enum object as text by calling `toString`.

```
String output = DayOfWeek.SATURDAY.toString() ;
```

Going the other direction, calling `DayOfWeek.valueOf`.

```
DayOfWeek dow = DayOfWeek.valueOf( "SATURDAY" ) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edited**

I made a small change in your code (it worked)

> **DateUtil**

```
class DateUtil {

private LocalDate date;

public DateUtil(LocalDate date) {
    this.date = date;
}

public String dayOfWeek() {
    return String.valueOf(date.getDayOfWeek());

    }
}
```

> **ChallengeThree**

```
public class ChallengeThree {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String theDayOfWeek = dayOfWeek("2000-01-01");
    System.out.println(theDayOfWeek);

}

public static String dayOfWeek(String date) {

    LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse(date);
    DateUtil dateUtil = new DateUtil(localDate);
    return dateUtil.dayOfWeek();

  }

}
```

Comment: It’s no nice way of solving the problem. We should prefer to keep the date as a `LocalDate` inside `DateUtil` as in the question. Also the comment in the code may mean that we are not allowed to change it.

Comment: @OleV.V. You're right, Thanks for the feedback, I edited it.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are fine. I wanted to go closer to what you asked precisely:

> It keeps saying 'cannot resolve method'?

As you have seen, the error message comes in this line:

```
     return LocalDate.of(theDate).getDayOfWeek();
```

The method it cannot resolve is `of()`. `LocalDate` has a couple of overloaded `of` methods. `theDate` is already a `LocalDate`, and as MadProgrammer said in the comment, there is no `of` method accepting a `LocalDate`. This is the reason for the error message. BTW, the message I get in my Eclipse says “The method of(int, Month, int) in the type LocalDate is not applicable for the arguments (LocalDate)”.

Since `theDate` is already a `LocalDate`, you don’t need that method call at all. Just leave it out and call `getDayOfWeek()` on `theDate` directly (I am on purpose leaving to yourself to put it into code; you’re the one supposed to learn from doing this, so you should be the one doing it).

It seems that you are having another problem in that `LocalDate.getDayOfWeek()` returns a `DayOfWeek` and your `DateUtil.dayOfWeek()` is supposed to return a `String`. You can likely solve it yourself when you get around to it. If not, feel free to follow up in comments.

As a complete aside, for production code I would consider a `DateUtil` class for this purpose overkill. I understand that this is an assignment, so I have answered it being faithful to the assignment as given.